Including the scope of the library broke Webpack rule regex
This is my config-overrides.js file in the root directory of my repo:
module.exports = function override(config) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /@org_name\/lib_name\/src\/path\/to\/large\.file\.js$/,
    use: "null-loader",
  });

  return config;
};


The above failed to exclude the specified file in the test property.
However, if I change the regex to:
test: /lib_name\/src\/path\/to\/large\.file\.js$/

it works.
In my React app, the above library is installed inside the node_modules directory, and the file does have a full path of:
node_modules/@org_name/lib_name/src/path/to/large.file.js

So I cannot understand why including the organization scope, @org_name, breaks the regex.
Here are the versions:
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.97.1"
  },

Here is the build script:
"scripts": {
  "build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192' react-app-rewired build",
},


Do some basic debugging - a test condition can be a function, so you can see what it's called with. But note that null-loader is deprecated.
